# What is the difference if I use a const reference as a parameter for a constexpr function instead of a type?

Tags: c++, constexpr

I have the following code:

```
inline constexpr int fibo(unsigned const &i) {
    if (i == 0) return 0;
    if (i == 1 || i == 2) return 1;

    return fibo(i - 1) + fibo(i - 2);
}
```

I received the following error message:

- ‘constexpr’ evaluation operation count exceeds limit of 33554432 (use -fconstexpr-ops-limit= to increase the limit)
- error: non-constant condition for static assertion static_assert(1'836'311'903 == fibo(46), "fibo(46)");

But if I use the following definition:

```
inline constexpr int fibo(unsigned i);
```

I don't receive an error message?

What are the implications if I use a const &?

Comment: Just a guess without knowing if this is really the reason, but it might be that without the `const &` tail call optimization is possible and with the `const &` it is not.

Comment: As written, iirc, this routine cannot do tail call optimization.  Because it needs to maintain a state in the frame to do the addition operation on the results of the recursion.

Comment: Seems only gcc has a difference. clang fails to compile in either case.

Comment: Notice than compiler doesn't have to do memoization. Doing memoization with value is simpler, whereas with (const) reference, value and address might be important, and with temporaries `i-1`, `i-2`, you never have same address. (it is true that `i` is not ODR-used, s value should be enough).